# Index 0 in empty address array reverts

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, arrays

I have a struct that has an array of addresses. When the address array is empty and I try to get index 0 I would expect it to return address(0), but instead it reverts. Any way around this?

```
struct KeyedMapAddressToBool {
  mapping(address => bool) data;
  mapping(address => uint) indices;
  address[] addresses;
}

function set(KeyedMapAddressToBool storage map, address key, bool value) public {
  map.data[key] = value;
  // THIS REVERTS
  address a = map.addresses[0];
}
```

EDIT:

I updated my struct to contain an exists mapping, but am wondering if there is another way. This works:

```
struct KeyedMapAddressToBool {
  mapping(address => bool) data;
  mapping(address => uint) indices;
  address[] addresses;
  mapping(address => bool) exists;
}

function set(KeyedMapAddressToBool storage map, address key, bool value) public {
  map.data[key] = value;
  if (map.exists[key] == false) {
    map.indices[key] = map.addresses.length;
    map.addresses.push(key);
    map.exists[key] = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When a dynamic array has `.length == 0` you can't access the first row to read or write because it doesn't exist. You can append to it with the `push()` method or increase with `.length++`.

`map.addresses[0]` would only run successfully if length is at least `1`.

You may find some ideas to help organize contract state over here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I added my solution to my question. I added an `exists` mapping.